# Error while running R from commandlne ubuntu : error while loading shared libraries: libpcre.so.1: cannot open shared object file

Tags: r, anaconda

Hi I am running R on Ubuntu : Getting this error:

> /home/user/anaconda3/lib/R/bin/exec/R: error while loading shared libraries: libpcre.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I have installed anaconda recently, I have tried

```
$echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

It shows nothing. I also tried

```
$sudo find / lib | grep libpcre.so.1
```

I want to run R on Ubuntu. It was running fine before; any hints?

Comment: Maybe you have to load some modules? Are you the administrator of the system?

Comment: Yes, I can run Sudo .. Please let me know what to do, I am trying every answer I find online regarding his But I am not able to set the $LD_LIBRARY_PATH,

Comment: sudo ldconfig : is also not doing any good..

Comment: I am not expert, but when using conda I have to run: export PATH=$PATH:/condapath/anaconda-3/bin and then run "source activate" to activate conda. Maybe someone with more experience can be of real help?